# How to select every Nth row in CSV file using python

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file with hundreds of rows, and I would like to select and export every 3 rows to a new CSV file with the new output CSV file being named after the first row of the selection.

For example in the following CSV file....

```
1980 10 12            
1  2  3  4  5  6  7       
4  6  8  1  0  8  6  
1981 10 12
2  4  9  7  5  4  1  
8  9  3  8  3  7  3
```

I would like to select the first 3 rows and export to a new CSV named "1980 10 12" based on the first row then select the next 3 rows and export to a new CSV named "1981 10 12" based on the first row of the next 3 rows. I would like to do this using python.

Comment: Please show your attempt to solve the problem and try to explain why it isn't working.

Comment: Are the CSV's formatted with `,` as the delimiter?

Comment: is it delimited by two space???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html), plus [`itertools.islice()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to select 3 rows each time:

```
import csv
import os.path
from itertools import islice


with open(inputfilename, 'rb') as infh:
    reader = csv.reader(infh)
    for row in reader:
        filename = row[0].replace(' ', '_') + '.csv')
        filename = os.path.join(directory, filename)
        with open(filename, 'wb') as outfh:
            writer = csv.writer(outfh)
            writer.writerow(row)
            writer.writerows(islice(reader, 2))
```

The `writer.writerows(islice(reader, 2))` line takes the next 2 rows from the reader, copying them across to the writer CSV, after writing the current row (with the date) to the output file first.

You may need to adjust the `delimiter` argument for the `csv.reader()` and `csv.writer()` objects; the default is a comma, but you didn't specify the exact format and perhaps you need to set it to a `'\t'` tab instead.

If you are using Python 3, open the files with `'r'` and `'w'` text mode, and set `newline=''` for both; `open(inputfilename, 'r', newline='')` and `open(filename, 'w', newline='')`.

Comment: Congrats on the 300k Martijn! :)

Comment: @MartijnPieters , That code works great, except my output CSV files only contain the first column of the first row. For example, for the first set of data, my output file is "1980.csv" and the second set of data is "1981.csv" when I would like the first set to be named "19801012.csv" based on the first 3 columns of the first row. How would I go about changing this? Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: @KoolKid: if the date is spread over 3 columns, just join them together; `filename = ''.join(row[:3] + '.csv'` would take the first 3 columns, join them into one string and append the `.csv` extension.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, so would the filename code look something like this... **filename = row[0].join(row[:3]) + '.csv'** because when I do that I get this output filename for the first group of values... **1980198010198012.csv**

Comment: @KoolKid: no, you want to use `''`, the empty string, as the joiner. My previous comment *is* missing a closing `)`, sorry about that. Corrected code: `filename = ''.join(row[:3]) + '.csv'`

Comment: @MartijnPieters thank you sooooooo much for the useful code! The first line of the exported group i.e. **1980 10 12** still gets exported to the new CSV. Do you know of a way to... 1.) remove this first row from each of the exported CSV's and 2.) insert 5 new rows of static data i.e. my name and my information to each output csv file? Thanks again!

Comment: @KoolKid: I inserted the first row explicitly, because your question implied you wanted that. Just remove the `writer.writerow(row)` line. You can add extra rows with `writer.writerow()` too, or add a series of rows (nested list of lists) with `writer.writerows()` (note the `s`) there).

Answer (score 2):

```
import csv
with open("in.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    chunks = []
    for ind, row in enumerate(reader, 1):
        chunks.append(row)
        if ind % 3 == 0: # if we have three new rows, create a file using the first row as the name
            with open("{}.csv".format(chunks[0][0].strip(), "w") as f1:
                wr = csv.writer(f1) 
                wr.writerows(chunks) # write all rows
            chunks = [] # reset chunks to an empty list
```

Comment: Why the separate counter when you could use `enumerate()` instead?

Comment: @MartijnPieters, how could I reset enumerate to 0?

Comment: You can use the `%` modulus operator.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, yep. I was going to do that but for some reason I thought the math would catch me out later, it has been a long week

Answer (score 0):

Using slight iterator trickery:

```
with open('in.csv', 'r') as infh:
    for block in zip(*[infh]*3):
        filename = block[0].strip() + '.csv'
        with open(filename, 'w') as outfh:
            outfh.writelines(block)
```

On Python 2.X you would use `itertools.izip`. The [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) actually mention `izip(*[iter(s)]*n)` as an idiom for clustering a data series.