# How to write on nth row in csv using Python?

Tags: python, csv

I have a following problem. Lets say I want to write a word on the cell in column = 1 & and row = 3.

I have written this function:

```
import csv

def write_to_csv(myfile, word):
    with open(myfile, "w", newline="") as csv_file:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
        write = [word]
        csv_writer.writerow(elt for elt in write)

write_to_csv("output.csv", "hello")
```

My function writes the word "hello" into the cell in column = 1 & and row = 1.

Now imagine that my output.csv already has someting in the first cell. And I don`t want to rewrite it. So how can I modify my function to write the word "hello" on column = 1 & and row = 3 ?

I found this queston, but it did not help me: [How to select every Nth row in CSV file using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26680453/how-to-select-every-nth-row-in-csv-file-using-python)

Thank you very much!

Comment: A file is just a stream of bytes. Once you inject something in the middle of that stream, you are overwriting whatever would have followed in the stream. (If you are writing something of exactly the same length as the bytes it should overwrite, you could in theory just overwrite individual bytes to the disk sectors which contain the file, but modern operating systems do not generally allow you to do this.)  So the answer to what you seem to be asking will be "make a copy of the parts you want to keep, and splice them around the new text, then replace the original file with the result".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A CSV file is a text file. That means that you should not try to overwrite it in place. The common way is to copy it to a new file *introducing your changes* at that time. When done, you move the new file with the old name.

Here is a possible code. It just hope that the file output.csv.tmp does not exist, but can be created and that output.csv has at least 4 lines:

```
def write_to_csv(myfile, word, row_nb, col_nb):
    """Updates a csv file by writing word at row_nb row and col_nb column"""
    with open(myfile) as csv_file, open(myfile+'.tmp', "w", newline='') as out:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
        csv_writer = csv.writer(out)
        #skip row_nb rows
        for i in range(row_nb):
            csv_writer.writerow(next(csv_reader))
        # read and change the expected row
        row = next(csv_reader)
        row[col_nb] = word
        # print(row)              # uncomment for debugging
        csv_writer.writerow(row)
        # copy last rows
        for row in csv_reader:
            csv_writer.writerow(row)

    # rename the tmp file
    os.remove(myfile)
    os.rename(myfile+'.tmp', myfile)

# write hello at first column of fourth row in output.csv
write_to_csv('output.csv', 'hello', 3, 0)
```